# Change controlgroup active button theme

Tags: javascript, jquery, mobile, jquery-mobile

I have a `controlgroup` and I am dynamically adding and removing `ui-btn-active` class to toggle the active button. The button toggles just fine, but I can't seem to find a way to change the active button theme.

> I want the in-active buttons to use the `d` theme and the active
>   buttons to use the `a` theme.
>
> Does anyone know how I can do this?

[image]

**HTML:**

```
<div data-role="controlgroup" data-type="horizontal">
    <a href="#" data-role="button" data-inline="true" data-mini="true" id="myApptBtn">My Appointments</a>
    <a href="#" data-role="button" data-inline="true" data-mini="true" id="allApptBtn">All Appointments</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Misread the question - please ignore my reply. Thx.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK so this is what I ended up doing.

**jQuery:**

```
$('[data-role="page"]').live('pageshow', function () {
    $('#myApptBtn').addClass('ui-btn-active');

    $('#myApptBtn').click(function () {
        $('#allApptBtn').removeClass('ui-btn-active');
        $('#myApptBtn').addClass('ui-btn-active');
    });

    $('#allApptBtn').click(function () {
        $('#myApptBtn').removeClass('ui-btn-active');
        $('#allApptBtn').addClass('ui-btn-active');
    });
});
```

**HTML:**

```
<li data-theme="d" class="li-state-small" style="text-align: center;">
    <div data-role="controlgroup" data-type="horizontal" class="btnFontSize12">
        <a href="#" data-role="button" data-inline="true" data-mini="true" id="myApptBtn">My Appointments</a>
        <a href="#" data-role="button" data-inline="true" data-mini="true" id="allApptBtn">All Appointments</a>
    </div>
</li>
```

**Answer to Question:**

So as it turns out, you can't override the theme via the markup.

[**Global "Active" state**](http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/api/themes.html)

> The jQuery Mobile framework uses a swatch called "active" (bright blue
>   in the default theme) to consistently indicate the selected state,
>   regardless of the individual swatch of the given widget. We apply this
>   in navigation and form controls whenever there is a need to indicate
>   what is currently selected. Because this theme swatch is designed for
>   clear, consistent user feedback, it cannot be overridden via the
>   markup; it is set once in the theme and applied by the framework
>   whenever a selected or active state is needed. The styling for this
>   state is in the theme stylesheet under the ui-btn-active style rules.

Comment: This solved the problem I was having with trying to change themes! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.addClass` and `.removeClass` functions of jQuery to perform this operation. Just set the active and inactive classes and change them onclick with the help of jQuery.

Here is the example. I'm not professional in jQuery, but this is working fine : [**Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/TwPzG/)

Comment: I have the toggle part working just fine. My question is: How do I get the in-active buttons to use the d theme and the active buttons to use the a theme? I don't want to add any custom CSS overwrites.