# Bizzare Jquery (Mobile) errors when using .find() or selecting a checkbox?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile, input, checkbox

So eh, while making a phone App with phonegap (and using jsconsole.com for debugging) I ran into this bizzare problem when I tried to access a input checkbox and 'check' it with JQuery depending on some scenarios. The problem is a lot more mysterious than that however...

Basic html is as such (inside a jqm-page), which runs from Adnroid Emulator:

```
<div data-role="controlgroup" data-type="horizontal" id="settings_bar">
    <input type="checkbox" name="isAFav" id="isAFav">
    <label for="isAFav">Favourite</label>
    <a href="#" data-role="button" data-icon="delete" data-iconpos="right" onclick="app.delete()">Delete</a>
</div>
```

When the page loads to display content I want to adjust the displayed info with a function which looks something like this:

```
if(isAFav){ // <-local variable from my runtime - it's valid
    try{
        var fav = $('#settings_bar').find("#isAFav");
        fav.attr('checked', 'true');
        fav.button('refresh');
    }catch(Err){
        console.log(err.message());
    }
}
```

The cryptic error that it throws is as such:

> Accessing selectionEnd on an input element that cannot have a selection.

The exact same thing happens for a multitude of:

```
$("#route_settings_bar").children('input');
$('input[name="isAFav"]');
```

I don't know what the hell is going wrong. I'm using the latest Jquery +mobile (1.9.1 & 1.3.0 respectively).

To add to the confusion, I previously named the form/id of the input as 'fav' and when I ran the corresponding code:

```
$('input[name="fav"]');
$("#route_settings_bar").children('input[name="fav"]'); //or this
```

we get this:
[image]

To me this looks like JqueryMobile code...what the %&^*? If anyone has any tips or suggestions, please help! Thanks!

P.S. I'm using a different jsconsole ID now.

Comment: Decided to go with the solution to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12095559/change-controlgroup-active-button-theme

However that still doesn't explain this insane bug - if anyone have any explanation - the question is still open, as it's the cause of the above I want to pinpoint!

Answer (score 1):

This is the correct way to check/uncheck checkbox/radio button' using `.prop` and the refresh it using `.checkboxradio('refresh')`.

```
if(isAFav){ 
 try{
  var fav = $('#settings_bar').find("#isAFav");
   fav.prop('checked', true); // here
   fav.checkboxradio('refresh'); // here
   // OR
   // fav.prop('checked', true).checkboxradio('refresh');
 }catch(Err){
   console.log(err.message());
 }
}
```

- **[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/3bjmJ/)**
- **[Reference](http://api.jquerymobile.com/checkboxradio/#method-refresh)**

Comment: The problem wasn't with setting the 'checked' state so to speak - but with 'selecting' the input field itself, see the image of the gibberish I got back!

Comment: Weird, I selected the input field by it `name` attribute and it worked. @Nisk

Comment: I know, it's bizarre - I mean, we get JQM function code back!

Comment: Yes and no - I tried the one phonegap suggests, the name started with D I believe, but it didn't work. Any suggestions?

Comment: Sorry @Nisk, no suggestions :)